# Chat Dark Theme Plus

Tags: script, chat

### About

Work in progress theme for StackExchange chats, also includes 'plugins' for additional features.

[image: sample picture]

Features include:

1. Inline webm/gifv
2. User colours
3. code-mode ([see here](https://i.imgur.com/XdJD87b.gifv)) activated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
4. Syntax Highlighting
5. Other stuff I can't think of.

#### Download

Install for Chrome here: [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/so-dark-chat-%20/bbkjccfnenmgidehjhaabamobpbaaghh)

### Contact

I can be reached at `rob.lemon@gmail.com`.

### Code

https://github.com/rlemon/se-chat-dark-theme-plus